# How can I prove that the inverse stereographic projection function is continuous?

Tags: continuity, stereographic-projections

Suppose we have the function $f(x, y) = (\frac{2x}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}, \frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}, \frac{x^2 + y^2 - 1}{x^2 + y^2 + 1})$

where $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to S^2 \setminus \{N\}$ where $N$ is the north pole of $S^2$

Can I prove that this is continuous without using topology, epsilon delta, or sequences?

I have read that "Clearly, it is a composition of continuous functions"

I just don't see which continuous functions I can use to compose the individual component functions.

I have also read that if you prove that the restriction to two different hemispheres is continuous, then the entire function is continuous.

I know that if $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} > 1$, a point in the plane gets mapped to the upper hemisphere, if $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 1$, to the equator, and if $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < 1$, to the lower hemisphere.

I prefer the easiest method. Thanks.

Comment: The component functions are rational: ratios of polynomials. In other words, the functions being composed are addition, multiplication, and division viewed as real-valued operations on ordered pairs of real numbers (avoiding division by $0$), and depending how fussy we want to be, restrictions of these together with inclusion maps (so that for example, $2x$ is viewed as inclusion $x \hookrightarrow (2, x)$ followed by multiplication).

Comment: Perfect, thanks!